# ASP.Net Application Crashes because of Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have an asp.net application that uses web service. At first the web service is working on our server. But after a while, the asp.net loops. Meaning the web service is not working. So, will restart it. It will work but after a while it will crash again. It's my first time in web service so I don't really know what I should do.

Comment: try debugging it using break-points. You may get some exceptions.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and finding out why "asp.net loops" (whatever that means)? If you want help, we need to know more details and what you've already tried.

Comment: This is really vague to provide any help. Are you getting any error while making web service call?

Comment: More details please. Why does it crash? Do you have a crash log? Can you isolate where the crash happens? There's no universal solution to app crashes. Every case is different.

Comment: The Web Service doesn't have any error on local. But when we deployed it in the server, it works at first then it doesn't. So, I can't really debug it.

Comment: Surely you can put log statements on your webservice and then investigate them?

Comment: There are no Error Logs showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thorough research, we found the problem last January or February I think. There were many disposable variables that is not disposed when we run code analysis in visual studio. So, we used **using** to dispose the variables that's causing the crashing not only from the web service but also from the applications that uses it.

`e.g.
    using(SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand())
    {
      **code here**
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Debug the webservice, if the webservice is also asp.net try out elmah for debugging.

https://code.google.com/p/elmah/

also available as nuget package, if you are using nuget.

Comment: The Web Service doesn't have any error on local. But when we deployed it in the server, it works at first then it doesn't. So, I can't really debug it.

Comment: That's why I pointed you to elmah to get debug logs in production

Comment: Even if the application is also in the same server? And we're just accessing it thru a link?

Comment: yes it doesn't matter, however when you want to debug the webservice you need to include elmah in the webservice. If you want to debug your asp.net app you need to include elmah in the app